# Live sreaming of results with rtweet package

Tags: r, twitter, streaming

I'm using the R package rtweet to stream live tweets.

Everything is ok, but what I want is to automatically store the information in Google Big Query and display it on Data Studio, and that information should be updated each X time (for example, 5 minutes).

How can I do it? The problem is that while sreaming, the R session is busy, so I can't do anything else.

I would also consider stopping the streaming for a second to store the information and resume it after...

Here is my code:

```
library(rtweet)
library(bigrquery)

token <- create_token(
  app = "app name",
  consumer_key = "consumer_key ",
  consumer_secret = "consumer_secret ",
  acess_token = "acess_token",
  access_secret = "access_secret")

palabras <- ""
streamtime <- 2 * 60
rt <- stream_tweets(q = palabras, timeout = streamtime)

#This is what I want to do each X time to store the information in Big Query:

insert_upload_job("project id", "dataset name", "table name", df, write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND")
```

Thanks to all,

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about R, but I had a similar case and there's nothing to do meanwhile `stream_tweets()` is running but wait the timeout.

I'm not sure if this is possible but, `stream_tweets()` creates a JSON object that is being filled meanwhile the function is running. Wouldn't be possible to run other R script in which when new item is added to the JSON store it to Big Query? Something like, split your code in two and run it parallely?

Hope my answer give you some ideas.